# HTML+CSS working on desktop but not on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, sass

I have a piece of legacy code below, and it works perfectly on desktop. But I am not able to render it on mobile.

Can you point in the right direction about what mistake I am making?

Thanks.

I have removed the url inside url(), but that is correct in the real code since it works on desktop.

```
<div class="summ_info" data-priority="2">
    <BubbleContent Data="@ViewModel.BubbleContent">
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <div class="icon_hover"></div>
    </BubbleContent>

    <Bubble Data="@ViewModel.BubbleContent" BubblePosition="right" TrianglePosition="top">
        <div>"Content"</div>
    </Bubble>
</div>
```

```
.dfinfo {
    @if($is-mobile) {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    @else {
        margin-bottom: 16px;
    }

    & > span {
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    .summ_info {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 14px;
        width: 14px;

        .BubbleContent {
            vertical-align: middle;
            height: inherit;
            width: inherit;
            padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: block;

            .icon{
                height: inherit;
                width: inherit;
                background-image: url(###);
                background-size: contain;
                display: block;
            }

            .icon_hover {
                height: 0px;
                width: 0px;
                background-image: url(###);
                background-size: contain;
            }

            &:hover .icon_hover {
                height: inherit;
                width: inherit;
            }

            &:hover .icon {
                display: none;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it that isn't working? If it is just the background image then double check that it can be read on whatever  mobile device you are using. Also, can you tell us what OS and browsers you are using and make your code into a runnable snippet so we can see the problem for ourselves. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What is ***$is-mobile***?

Answer (score 0):

Add this meta tad in `<head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

HTML5 introduced a method to let web designers take control over the viewport, through the  tag.

You should include the following  viewport element in all your web pages:

---

2. 

Sometimes we need a little Javascript code snippet to detect if user use mobile device, the simplest way is detecting its browser user agent.

We use the regular expression test to detect if browser is a mobile device like:
if

```
if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
  // true for mobile device
  document.write("mobile device");
}else{
  // false for not mobile device
  document.write("not mobile device");
}
```

Comment: The ```.sum_info``` css (and everything under it) is not getting rendered on mobile. It is getting rendered on desktop. The "is-mobile" is set correctly.

Comment: please check in above answer nom.  2